# Reusing piece of HTML + knockout

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, knockout.js

Basing on [nice tutorial](http://david.ingledow.co.uk/blog/google-material-designs-animated-loading-spinner-svg-and-css/) I've created an overlay with Google-style spinner. HTML in my case is minimum and looks like following:

```
        <div class="spinner-wrapper" data-bind="visible: spinnerVisible">
            <svg class="spinner" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
                <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="4" stroke-miterlimit="10" />
            </svg>
        </div>
```

Note the `data-bind="visible: spinnerVisible"`.

I'd like to reuse this among different places in my application to avoid DRY problems. What approach may I take? Keep in mind, that visibility of the spinner wrapper will be controlled by different viewmodels (although I may guarantee each one to have `spinnerVisible` property).

Comment: You can take a look at [Custom elements](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a [(template-only) knockout component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-binding.html#note-template-only-components) with the new [web component-like syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html).

Two steps to get it to work:

### 1. Register a component and define its template paramaters:

Here, you define your template and the parameters it needs to render. In your case, only a named observable that controls the visible binding.

```
ko.components.register('spinner', {
    template:
        '<div data-bind="visible: spinnerVisible">A spinner<hr/></div>'
});
```

### 2. Use it with the correct parameters in your HTML

Now, whatever your viewmodel's spinner controlling property may be, you can reuse the same component to render it. For example:

```
<spinner params="spinnerVisible: loading"></spinner>
<spinner params="spinnerVisible: pendingRequests().length > 0"></spinner>
```

Note that if you use the regular `component` binding, you'll lose some of the clean syntax.

Here's an example showing the code above in action:

```js
ko.components.register('spinner', {
    template:
        '<div data-bind="visible: visible">A spinner<hr/></div>'
});

ko.applyBindings({

  someProp: ko.observable(true)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<p>Regular syntax</p>
<div data-bind="component: {
  name: 'spinner',
  params: { visible: someProp }
}"></div>

<p>Web component</p>
<spinner params='visible: someProp'></spinner>

<button data-bind="click: someProp.bind(null, !someProp())">toggle</button>
```